# What's the easiest way for a Java Swing client to consumer a webservice?

Tags: java, swing, web-services, wsdl

I have a Java Swing application client that I want to use to consume certain webservices, but I want to make it as painless as possible to code (because really all I want is the info). I do understand that whatever solution is used will need to stub the POJO's too.

If you'd like to give a demo, that would be great, or if you can point to a tutorial that would also be really appreciated.

I did look at Axis, including the more recent Axis2, but it's a bit more complex than I was hoping (aka. I have to learn something). At least just for some quick prototype testing and not real development, more for the sake of just saying I can, is there something or a tutorial out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say it, but the easiest way was [to actually learn Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5/userguide-creatingclients.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/.

Comment: What folder within eclipse do you drop it in (there's no documentation or update link).

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing the web service yourself?  Use springframework's HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean and HttpInvokerServiceExporter.  I use these and swear by them.

Also you want to use apache's HttpClient.

Are you using someone else's web service?  Pick a framework (axis/castor/metro?) and have it generate stubs.

Comment: I am not writing the webservice. As an analogy, I would just want to connect to a twitter, facebook, amazon, etc. web service within a desktop client just to test that I can.